# How to debug "Index was outside the bounds of the array" in DNN

Tags: c#, debugging, dotnetnuke

I know this error and tens of questions have already being asked. But my question is not about "why", it's about "how to debug".

I have installed a DNN CMS, and have developed a module for it. Sometimes it throws this error:

```
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__58`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Web.Http.Services.DefaultServices.GetServices(Type serviceType)
at System.Web.Http.ServicesExtensions.GetServices[TService](ServicesContainer services)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderAttribute.GetModelBinderProvider(HttpConfiguration configuration)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderAttribute.GetModelBinder(HttpConfiguration configuration, Type modelType)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderAttribute.GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.DefaultActionValueBinder.GetParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
at System.Array.ConvertAll[TInput,TOutput](TInput[] array, Converter`2 converter)
at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.DefaultActionValueBinder.GetBinding(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.ActionValueBinderTracer.System.Web.Http.Controllers.IActionValueBinder.GetBinding(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor.get_ActionBinding()
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem..ctor(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.GetInternalSelector(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction>b__0()
at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)
at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpActionSelectorTracer.System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

As you can see there is no footprint of my code anywhere. It's all system code, and I don't know how to troubleshoot and debug this. I just restart my application pool and everything works fine, and after a while again this error appears.

How should I debug this error? How do I find the root of the problem?

For anyone who think this is a module! , this is a simple Web-Api as you see in this image :

[image: Simple Web-Api]

Comment: share the code and point the line that gives you the exception

Comment: Dear @un-lucky, if I knew which part of my code causes this problem, I wouldn't ask this question of course. :D The problem is that I can't share my entire project here. I have no idea to share what.

Comment: I'm working with DNN too & I know it's too hard to track the issue, specially if you are new in DNN, first make sure you set `debug="false"` inside `web.config`, if this code is part of `dll`, add `.pdb` file(s) too, then check the `EventLogs` table. please report if you did this part or not.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I did both of them. The errors does not appears in `EventLogs`.

Comment: @EghbalSohrabi Please mention DNN version, also is that code within normal UserControl (_CodeFile mode_), or in DLL (_Class library or UserControl, CodeBehind mode_)?

Comment: @mehdi-dehghani if you take a look at the image I attached you will see that there is a web-api , and also for your information my DNN version is 8.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an array that is intermittently not getting values. Showing us the code would really help.

Breakpoints should help you. Then, check the `Locals` and `Autos` window to find out why is it not getting any value.

Comment: I mentioned that I know "why" I'm getting this error. It's not about "not knowing and trying to find out". It's about "how to resolve it".

Answer (score 1):

I use a `try-catch` block in the `Page_Load` of the module that catches the `ProcessModuleLoadException` should it occur.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        buildModule();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, ex);
    }
}
```

Whenever there is an error in the module, it will not crash DNN completely and it will log the error in the Event Viewer.

Comment: I don't know which module causes this error.Where should I put this `try-catch` ?

Comment: Ideally it would be in the `Page_Load` of every module.

Comment: please check the Image I attached, The `Object reference...` and that `index was outside ...` , are happen lots of time. there is no web-form module , it is a web-api project.